# Modifying PATH in Linux

Tags: linux, path

I recently installed linux, been trying to append stuff to my PATH but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my config file (~/.bashrc)

```
echo "Executing .bashrc ..."
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/files/scripts
```

For example: i have a file "script_name.sh" in ~/scripts. I type "script_name" in a terminal and it gives an error: script_name: command not found. Am i missing something here?

Comment: it should have worked, try adding a slash(/) at the end.. and export the path again. and what does echo $PATH has

Comment: you need to enter `script_name.sh`, not just `script_name`. The `.sh` is not automatically added on linux, it's part of the command name. Or you can rename the script to `script_name`, the extension doesn't really have a meaning on linux.

Comment: thanks, i had a typo aswell, but it started working after writing th file extension aswell. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try `chmod +x myscript.sh`

this will make the script executable.

On GNU/Linux (ie Unix), execution permission is require for execution.

(+x = make it executable)